# Hive StorageHandler throws exception "Configuration and input path are inconsistent"

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have a `HiveStorageHandler` if I do `select * from myTable` it returns all the rows in the underlying storage.

When I do something like `select col1 from myTable` the underlying mapreduce job throws an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:119)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Configuration and input path are inconsistent
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:90)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Configuration and input path are inconsistent
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:520)
    ... 23 more
2015-02-12 15:45:51,881 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

If I introduce a  `HiveMetaHook.preCreateTable` and set the location to what my input-path on hdfs is then it works.  But my path changes dynamically, and I can't constantly update this property:

```
 @Override
    public void preCreateTable(Table tbl) throws MetaException {
        if (tbl.getSd().getLocation() != null) {
            throw new MetaException("LOCATION should be null.");
        }

         tbl.getSd().setLocation(*hard-coded-input-path*);
    }
```

I did this based on the following [posting](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/sKj1qocsBAg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because I was changing the the `mapred.input.dir` on the fly to point to a particular file on hdfs.  Now, once i'm finished with own calculations, I set the `mapred.input.dir` back to what hive had set it to.

I have my own `Split` for this `InputFormat`.  So every-time `FileSplit.getPath()` is invoked I return what hive expects which is the original `mapred.input.dir` and now everything works.

```
class MySplit extends org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit {

public MySplit(InputSplit actualSplit, String hiveInputPath) {
  super (new Path(hiveInputPath), 0,0, (String[]) null);
  this.actualSplit = actualSplit;
}

//do not override getPath that way hiveInputPath is returned

InputSplit getActualSplit() {
  return actualSplit;
}

....
}
```